# Best AWS way to update S3 bucket daily?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

**This is the current architecture:**

- user data saves into DynamoDB
- statistic data saves into S3 (25000 JSON objects, 65KB/object)
- app authenticates the user through a lambda with DynamoDB
- app reads the statistic from a API gateway endpoint, which triggers a lambda which reads from S3 and return it (one S3 object each time).
- the statistic data needs to be updated, and I have a passive updating logic in-place. Every time the lambda reads data from S3, I will check the MetaData, and overwrite the existing one if it is outdated.

**Everything works fine, but now the requirement changes.**

- we need to do some analytics against all the 25000 objects on a daily basis.
- the analytic must be done after updating all the 25000 JSON objects

**What's the best AWS way to do it?**

I was thinking just:

1. having a prebuilt list,
2. then use a lambda to push all the update command onto an SQS on a daily basis (trigger by an EventBridge), then,
3. in turn, triggers a lambda processor to update the S3 object one by one.
4. When the queue is empty, use AWS Athena to do the analysis,
5. save the result to a DynamoDB table, done.

Is there any better way to do it, is it too much for using lambda for pushing 25000 messages onto SQS? Will it take a very long time? I will handle duplicate message in the lambda, so can use the standard queue.

Comment: You could look into S3 Batch Operations - if it's always the same objects, that may help.

Comment: Are you saying that 25,000 _new_ objects arrive every day, or the objects simply stay around each day for updating? What do you mean by "update these objects"? Objects in Amazon S3 cannot be edited, they can only be overwritten. Why are you keeping 25,000 objects in S3 rather than using a database? How big is each file? Can you tell us more about what you are actually doing, so that we can provide a more appropriate answer? It is hard to give advice without understanding _why_ you are doing these activities.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for the reply man. it is overwriting. Each file is like 60KB, do not want to save to the DB, to save the headache of VPC related stuff, do not think we need it. User saves into the DynamoDB and data goes to S3, no DB involved. :)

Comment: Can you expand upon what you mean by "User saves into the DynamoDB and data goes to S3"? Is this process currently working, or are you asking how to get the data into S3 from DynamoDB? If the data is already in DynamoDB, why do you want to export it as 25,000 separate objects? (Please Edit your question to add more details rather than answering in the comments.)

Comment: Thanks updated :) @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are asking:

1. How to query the 25,000 JSON files in S3, and
2. How to force the update of all those files *prior* to doing the querying.

**Amazon Athena** should be fine for #1. It would cost approximately `25,000 x 60Kb x $5/TB = $0.0075` per query. This cost could be reduced by saving in a compressed gzip format, or using something other than JSON files. You can test the querying on the current (outdated) files to confirm that it works as desired. I would recommend testing it on a subset of files (eg 100 files) to confirm it can do what you want.

Your plan for **forcing the update** on the 25,000 files seems good, which would presumably involve pushing 25,000 messages into an Amazon SQS queue that then triggers AWS Lambda functions. You could code the functions to handle multiple messages up to a batch size of 10, or limit the batch size to 1 and process one message per function execution.

The **time required** would depend upon how long it takes to process each JSON file, but the Lambda function can run in parallel (by default up to 1000 concurrent executions, but with the ability to burst higher, see: [AWS Lambda quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)). I recommend you test it on a subset of files first (eg start with 10 or 100 messages in the queue).

There is no limit to the number of messages sent to an Amazon SQS queue.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, especially for the price calculation here, was thinking about parquet for saving. For the calculation, 25000*65KB = 1625000KB = 0.001625TB, X $5/TB = $0.008125 per query?

Comment: D'oh, my error! `KB -> MB -> GB -> TB` is `÷ 1024^3`, making it under 1c per query. Go for it! The most efficient format is Snappy compressed, partitioned Parquet. See: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)